# label_bquote() doesn't work with column faceting in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-grid

Though I have been able to get `label_bquote()` to work with `geom_raster()` when faceting into rows, it seemingly does not work when faceting into columns. Here is a reproducible example, where the rasters are faceted into rows, giving the correct output:

```
library(ggplot2)
d = expand.grid(
   X = c(1, 2, 3),
   Y = c(1, 2, 3),
   Z = c(1, 2, 3)
)

set.seed(123)
d$A = runif(27)

p = ggplot(
   data = d
) +
   geom_raster(
      mapping = aes(
         x = X,
         y = Y,
         fill = A
      )
   ) + facet_grid(
      Z ~ .,
      labeller = label_bquote(
         "Z Value ="~ .(Z)
       )
   )
```

The output is as you would expect:

[image: Correct graphic]

However if the `facet_grid()` formula is changed to show columns instead of rows:

```
) + facet_grid(
          . ~ Z,
          labeller = label_bquote(
             "Z Value ="~ .(Z)
           )
       )
```

Then the bquote labelling is ignored, and only the parsed labelling is used:

[image: Incorrect graphic]

What is causing this please?

EDIT: I should have added: I am using ggplot2 version 3.1.0 from CRAN.

Comment: Seems like a bug. Also note the "new" (2.0) style for ggplot is to use `rows=vars()` or `cols=vars()` for faceting (see `?facet_grid` help) but even in that case it breaks. I'd report this as an issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues

Comment: Thanks, I'll report later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported it as a bug but apparently it's not... see [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3333).

> label_bquote() has both rows and cols arguments! You'll need to specify which is which to get it working with facet_grid().

Or in the [ggplot2 manual](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/label_bquote.html):

```
label_bquote(rows = NULL, cols = NULL, default)
```